# Sort array (duplicated data, 0 value and NaN)

Tags: matlab, duplicates, unique

Good morning/afternoon ~~

I have to sort the following array, and replace some value with 0.

```
A=[9 NaN 7 7 7 7 NaN 7 7 7 7 NaN 9 9 9 NaN 4 4 4 4 NaN ] 

% The output should be>>> 

A=[9 NaN 7 0 0 0 NaN 7 0 0 0 NaN 9 0 0 NaN 4 0 0 0 NaN ]
```

By using the unique() function, the 7 after the second NaN and  the 9 after the third NaN, will be replaced by 0.
so I can only get the results as:

```
[c, ia] =  unique(A, 'first');
t = A;
t(iA) =0;
A = A-t;

A=[9 NaN 7 0 0 0 NaN 0 0 0 0 NaN 0 0 0 NaN 4 0 0 0 NaN ]
```

How could I resolve this issure?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about brute force?

```
% Data
A_in = [9 NaN 7 7 7 7 NaN 7 7 7 7 NaN 9 9 9 NaN 4 4 4 4 NaN]; 

% Processing
A_out = zeros(size(A_in));
prev_char = [];
for ii=1:numel(A_in), 
    if A_in(ii)==prev_char
        A_out(ii)=0;
    else
        A_out(ii)=A_in(ii);
    end
    prev_char = A_in(ii);
end
```

Comment: I am glad I helped you. Don't forget to accept the valid answer to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized solution:

```
% Flip A (or you will zero out every one in the sequence except the last one)
B      = A(end:-1:1);
dfB    = diff(B);
idx    = ~isnan(dfB);
B(idx) = dfB(idx);

% Flip back into A
A = B(end:-1:1)
```

**EDIT**
Without creating B, a bit more obscure:

```
dfA = diff(A(end:-1:1));
A([false ~isnan(dfA(end:-1:1))]) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you!! OMG the flip method so clever! =)